# Pics Download from Facebook in Windows phone

Tags: pictures

I'm unable to find a picture downloaded from fb inbox.

Kindly guide.!!

Comment: are you using the Facebook app or website?

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving Photos from `Facebook` App, it goes to `Pictures App -> Saved Pictures`.

from `Files` App go to `SDCard/Phone -> Pictures -> Saved Pictures`.